# Checking in mypy that a specific object doesn't rely on missing imports?

Tags: python, python-3.x, mypy, python-typing

I'm aware that mypy's `--ignore-missing-imports` option results in imported modules without type hints having type `Any`.

As a result, the following returns a typing error:

```py
class Bar(int): ...
    
def foo(a: str) -> None: ...

foo(Bar())  # error: Argument 1 to "foo" has incompatible type "Bar"; expected "str"
```

but this doesn't:

```py
import foobar  # library without type hints

class Bar(int, foobar.baz): ... # note the additional base class
    
def foo(a: str) -> None: ...

foo(Bar())  # ok
```

**My question is: is there any way to specify or test that a specific variable (in this case `Bar`) doesn't rely on/inherit from missing imports?**

I would like to catch any change to `Bar` that results in it being made essentially typeless. I coud easily add a runtime unit test to ensure that `Bar` doesn't inherit from `foobar` specifically, but I would like to handle all possible changes that make `Bar` behave like `Any`.

I could also add a test that I expect to fail with mypy (like the last line of the examples above) and make sure it does, but that involves adding a new type of quality check job which seems overkill.

Comment: Try with    `--disallow-any-unimported` or `--disallow-subclassing-any` command line mypy options.

Comment: Perfect, thank you! (the other dynamic typing flags are also interesting: https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/command_line.html#disallow-dynamic-typing)